# Which is the most secured machine key encryption method?

Tags: iis, encryption, iis-6, machinekey

Currently, I am generating the machine key with the validation method 'SHA1'. As I want to generate a more secured machine key than 'SHA1', I have chosen the HMACSHA256 validation. But it is not available in older Windows versions like Windows Server 2008. So, I want to know which one the best (secured) validation method than SHA1 and SHA2.

Comment: What do you mean by the `validation method`?  What are you indend to use it for?

Comment: Refer this image https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zWj2DTou2UnYHmxL1eI5KFVcaPLeDg8C. I am using the machine key to configure the web application in IIS.